# Vim plugin and .vimrc asynchronous error on Linux screen

Tags: linux, vim

I installed **Linux screen** for multiple window work. But I found the vim plugin and `.vimrc` load fail on opened screen.

I used the following command to reload the `.vimrc`:

```
vim +PluginInstall +qall
```

and get the error information

> Not an editor command: PluginInstall

Comment: Read `vim --help`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's happening because `PluginInstall` is a [vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) command?

Follow the instructions in the Readme to get it working in your project.